# How to Create a Comprehensive Character Mapping from Regular to Bold Text in JavaScript, Similar to YayText?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, character-encoding, text-processing

I am working on a project that requires transforming standard text into its bold equivalent, similar to the functionality provided by YayText. My goal is to create a JavaScript function that takes any input (including letters, numbers, and symbols), finds the appropriate Unicode character, and converts it into its bold representation.

So far, I have started creating a mapping for some of the characters, but I'm not sure how to proceed for a comprehensive solution. Here is a snippet of what I have:

```
const boldMap = {
    'a': '', 'b': '', 'c': '', // ... would like to continue for other alphabets
    'A': '', 'B': '', 'C': '', // ... continuing for uppercase and all alphabets
    '1': '', '2': '', '3': '', // ... continuing for numbers
    // ... (I would also like to include symbols like !"#¤%&/()=?`etc)
};
```

I am looking for guidance on the following aspects:

**Completing the Character Map:** How can I extend this mapping to cover all relevant characters, including special and accented characters? Is there already something done online that is full or can at least be made into a character map suitable for JS?

**Identifying Bold Equivalents:** Is there a standard way to find the bold equivalent of each character, or do I need to manually map each one? Or, is this already done for me somewhere?

**Handling Missing Characters:** For characters that don't have a bold equivalent, what would be the best approach?

**Performance Optimization:** Given the extensive nature of the character set, are there any performance considerations for implementing this in a web application?

I'm open to any suggestions, best practices, or resources that could help me create a robust and efficient text-to-bold converter.

Thank you for your help!

I've begun writing a JavaScript script that maps standard alphanumeric characters to their bold equivalents for a text styling feature. The aim is for users to input text, and the script will return the text in a bold Unicode format that can be used on platforms like Facebook.

Here's a condensed version of the mapping and script I've written:

```
// Sample of the character mapping
const boldMap = {
    'a': '', 'b': '', 'c': '', /* ... */, 'A': '', /* ... */, '0': '',
    'ä': '̈', /* ... */, 'ß': '', /* ... */, '?': '?', /* etc. */
};

// Sample of the script that applies the mapping
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    /* ... Code to handle form submission and convert input text ... */
});
```

I expected to be able to expand this mapping to include a complete set of characters, covering all the alphabets, numbers, and special characters. The script should then be able to take any given text and convert it into its bold equivalent if one exists, or leave the character as is if it doesn't.

So far, the conversion works for the standard Latin alphabet and numbers. But it does not work for the other Latin based alphabet or the symbols. I don't have the characters for those.

Comment: Switch to [Facebook Workplace Markdown](https://www.internetivo.com/clients/knowledgebase/138/Facebook-Workplace-Markdown.html). There are merely 584 codepoints found in the [Unicode database](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) with *BOLD* in name, and some of them repeatedly e.g. - `` (U+1D41A, *MATH BOLD SMALL A*)
- `` (U+1D482, *MATH BOLD ITALIC SMALL A*)
- `` (U+1D4EA, *MATH BOLD SCRIPT SMALL A*)
- `` (U+1D586, *MATH BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL A*)
- `` (U+1D5EE, *MATH SANS-SERIF BOLD SMALL A*)
- `` (U+1D656, *MATH SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC SMALL A*) etc…